# I can’t pray on time since im in school as a teacher

Tags: prayer-timings

السلام عليكم
I’m a teacher and I spend most of the day in school , my problem is that I can never pray duhr or 'asr at the time of the azan , I have to always wait for another hour when I will a 10 minutes break and pray .

My question is : is it possible For me to pray duhr and 'asr together during the 10 minutes break ? Even though it will be after the duhr prayer and before 'asr prayer

Comment: Please clarify praying at the time of azan isn't necessary for having prayed on time because prayer times are rather time spans. So in many cases praying an hour after azan is totally fine. Else the topic of prayer times is mostly covered on the site from almost all perspectives, therefore I strongly assume that your question was already covered.